# How do you generate dynamic <style> tag content in Angular template at runtime?

Tags: html, css, angular, highcharts, angular-material

I have an Angular component that generates `mat-checkbox` dynamically at runtime and I need to change the individual background of each checkbox differently with different color and I don't (won't) have the information before hand, only available at runtime.

I have the following `ng-template` for the checkboxes:

```
<ng-template #renderCheckbox let-id="id" let-attr="attr">
  <mat-checkbox 
    [checked]="attr.show"
    [color]="'custom-' + id"
    (change)="onChange($event.checked, attr)">
    {{attr.name}}
  </mat-checkbox>
</ng-template>
```

where, `attr` in the template has the following interface type, these infomation are pulled from `Highcharts`' series and I didn't want to hardcode the `color`.

```
interface LinkedSeriesAttributes {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  index: number;
  color: string;
  checked: boolean;
}
```

Since there is no way to create css classes before hand and there is no way to directly apply color to the `mat-checkbox`, I could only generate the `<style>...</style>` right at the beginning of my template.

In my component, I have code that will generate the style which would give me something like this:

```
  .mat-checkbox.mat-custom-hello.mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background::before {
    color: #6E8BC3 !important;
  }

  .mat-checkbox.mat-custom-world.mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background::before {
    color: #9ED6F2 !important;
  }
  ...
```

However, I tried various ways to dump it inside `<style>` without success. I tried:

```
<style>{{ dynamicCSSStyles }}</style>
```

Which, my IDE shows that's an error with the curly braces, although it compiled fine and ran without errors, I got nothing, can't even see the `<style>` tag.

I also tried to include `<style>` inside my `dynamicCSSStyles` variable, and angular just dumped the whole thing out as text...

What's the correct way to generate a `<style>` in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a **REALLY** dirty way of "making this work" but it causes Angular to keep adding the `<style>` back into the DOM.

First, set `encapsulation` to `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Second, create a function to generate the `<style>` tag the old fashion way **with an id**:

```
  updateDynsmicStyleNode() {
    const id = 'dynamic-css-styles';
    const nativeElm = this.elmRef.nativeElement;
    const existing = nativeElm.querySelector(`style#${id}`);
    if (!existing) {
      const styleTag = document.createElement('style');
      styleTag.setAttribute('id', id);
      styleTag.innerHTML = this.dynamicCSSStyles;
      nativeElm.prepend(styleTag);
    } else {
      existing.innerHTML = this.dynamicCSSStyles;
    }
  }
```

Third, call our function in `ngAfterViewChecked`:

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.updateDynsmicStyleNode();
  }
```

I mean while this worked, **it is really bad**, since moving the mouse around the screen would cause Angular to just continuously reinsert the `<style>` tag.

Does anyone know some other way more legit to archive this? LOL

Comment: The quickest fix to what you have here is to make a variable `_dynamicCSSStyles: string` and only update `innerHtml` if the value has changed. So you'd only update `innerHTML` if `this.dynamicCSSStyles != _dynamicCSSStyles`. But the bigger issue is you're doing it during `ngAfterViewChecked` (which happens a lot) instead of only when it has actually changed. Another thing that may help is `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on the component (but that's part of a broader strategy to avoid unnecessary change detection activity).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngClass` or `[class]` attribute. Since you can have the styles ready from the component.ts file.

You can do something like this:

```
Way 1: If you already know what the dynamic ids might be, (like if it always will be 'hello' and 'world')

let dynamicClasses = {};

// Once you get some classes from your logic, you can add them to the object above

dynamicClasses['hello'] = 'custom-hello';
dynamicClasses['world'] = 'custom-world';

// Then in HTML
<mat-checkbox [ngClass]="dynamicClasses"></mat-checkbox>



Way 2: If you dont know what the classes also might be, like if its not always be hello or world, then create a method and call it where required, you might need to do something similar to @codenamezero said.
```

Comment: The colors and the values are not predetermined. So even if I have a CSS class sitting somewhere, I won't know the color.

Comment: Can you give the sample of the code where you are getting the dynamic info from and how you are getting it? I mean the value(s). So that i can take a look at the code and maybe suggest you something

Comment: I've added something in the first post, but essentially, I was trying to read the series from multiple `Highcharts` dynamically, parse its series to get the `id`, `name`, `index`, `color` etc and then dynamically generate a brunch of checkboxes on the fly to toggle them. I've already gotten it to work, except that I wanted the `mat-checkbox` background-color to match the series color.

Comment: If there is no real simple, easy way to archive what I'm trying to do, I guess I have no other choice but to enforce/limit the colors ahead of time instead of grabbing and setting them dynamically like that. It would've worked if I didn't use `mat-checkbox`, but because I'm using `mat-checkbox` and there is no attribute for me to set/change it directly, is much harder to manipulate the colors.